# z-index doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

I used the following HTML5 and CSS3 code to render a star shape and some text to appear inside. I tried setting the z-index for the p tag to 1 and then 10, but the complete text doesn't appear above the star shape. Only part of the text inside the paragraph appears. Can someone explain to me why?

HTML5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="star-five"><p>Hello Weaver!</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3 code:

```
p { 
  font-size: 20px; 
  color: #000000;
  z-index: 10;
}

#star-five {
   z-index: 5;
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
}
#star-five:before {
   z-index: 5;
   border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

}
#star-five:after {
   z-index: 5;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` does not work on elements that have `position:static` (ie. no `position` set). Since your `p` has no `position`, it's not factoring in the `z-index`.

Set `position:relative` on the `p`.

Alternatively, use a negative `z-index` on the `:before` element, as in Benio's answer - this works because the "container" `#star-five` defines a stacking context (by having its own `z-index`). Otherwise a negative `z-index` would move it behind the `<body>`!

Answer (score 2):

It works, you have just write `-5` instead of `5`.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfK92/).